# Having trouble passing parameters between threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to update a working thread running behind a Swing GUI, am finding once the Thread has started it seems to be ignoring any parameters being changed/updated etc.

Connection class:

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    initilizeConnection();
    while (processing == true) {
        if (connected == true) {
            fetchFolders();
            System.out.println("New Folder selected: "+directory);
            if (directory == null) {
                directory = "INBOX";
            }
            fetchMessages();
        }
    }

}

public void setDirectory(String directory) {
    this.directory = directory;
}
```

GUI end:

```
private void providerListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    this.alisas = providerList.getSelectedValue().toString();
    if (this.alisas != null) {
        getThreadEmails().setNick(this.alisas);
        Thread r = new Thread(getThreadEmails());
        r.start();
        if (getThreadEmails().isConnected() == true) {
            populateFoldersList();
            populateTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Once a user has clicked an item from the list, the value is stored, this is passed to the connection class, this part works, however when am selecting a folder from another list and passing this into the thread, the run method still says directory has null.

```
private void updateTable() {
    dir = folderList.getSelectedValue().toString();
    getThreadEmails().setDirectory(dir);
    populateTable();
}
```

I've spent hours trying to resolve this issue but to no avail.

Comment: what `getThreadEmails()` does?

Comment: does `getThreadEmails` always return the same object? may be you can show first.

Comment: its just a getter/setter of an object of a class, everything is passed through it.

Comment: private final ThreadedEmailManager threadEmails = new ThreadedEmailManager(); what would you like me to show besides this? the getThreadEmails() simply encapsulate the object threadEmails. PS did solve the issue, although the table itself isn't being updated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to show more of your code for us to really understand what you're trying to do.

You have a basic problem in your terminology. You're not trying to talk to a Thread, you're trying to talk to the object running inside the Thread. So when you create the Thread and start it, if you need to talk to the object later, you need to retain a handle to it.

So let us assume you have Thead a (your main UI thread) and Thread b (your email handler guy). The OBJECT running inside Thread a keeps a handle to the OBJECT running inside Thread b. Call that handle emailHandler.

Then at some point, the user does something. Your code then does:

```
emailHandler.doSomething(arguments);
```

You can have doSomething() manipulate anything you want within your object. But the thing is, doSomething() is going to get called inside Thread a, not Thread b.

So you probably need your EmailHandler object to check the values you're manipulating so he knows he is supposed to do something. And you probably need to use wait() and notify() to have the thread wake up....

Multi-threaded programming is not for the weak at heart. Most of us learn how by reading a few books on it.

---

I spent some time thinking about this. I'm going to share a design pattern you are going to want to know.

You have two threads. One thread needs to pass work to the other thread. The pattern we use is pretty simple.

```
public class WorkQueue {
    private ArrayList<WorkItem> list = new ArrayList<WorkItem>();

    public synchronized void giveWork(arguments) {
        WorkItem item = new WorkItem();
        ... set fields on item that describe what the other thread should do
        list.add(item);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized WorkItem getSomethingToDo() {
        while (list.size() == 0) {
            try {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
        WorkItem item = list.get(0);
        list.removeAt(0);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Then your work thread looks like:

```
WorkItem item;

while ((item = workQueue.getSomethingToDo()) != null) {
     // do whatever you're supposed to do
 }
```

Comment: okay firstly am passing a nick name from the GUI into the thread, and inform the thread its time to stop being lazy and do something. Next i attempt to connect to an email provider, by fetching saved login details and ofc decrypting the password before attempting to login. Once successful, the directory would be null at this stage due it has not yet fetch the folders for the user to click on. Once the connection has been established the folders are fetched and shown to the user, from this point the user can select a folder from the list and its contents is displayed in a jTable(headers).

Comment: Joseph you are right, do you have any examples in relation to communicating with the thread? That's exactly what I really need to do.

Comment: If you want to be a LOT more specific, then this might be the right venue. But if you're trying to understand multi-threaded programming, as I said -- most of us read several entire BOOKS about it. If you do a Google search for "java multithreading" -- you'll see there are a ton of books out there.

Comment: I added a design pattern to try.